# How to remove all files with same extension except one with rm

Tags: regex, wildcard, zsh, rm

I want to remove all files with .o extension except the specific example.o, how can I do that with rm?
Edit:
Environment: zsh

Comment: Are you doing it on Unix/Linux?

Comment: Regex is `.+?(?<!example)\.o`

Comment: And what is your "environment", bash script, sh script, zsh, fish, ...? you see, different shells might have subtle differences regarding wildcards and regular expressions

Comment: The environment is zsh. Sorry for not mentioning that.

Answer (score 2):

In `zsh`, you may use `KSH_GLOB` that works as `extglob` of `bash`:

```
setopt KSH_GLOB

echo rm !(example).o
```

Other option is to use `extended_glob` with a slightly different globbing syntax:

```
setopt extended_glob

echo rm (^example).o
```

Where `^` is used for negation.

Once you're satisfied with the output, remove `echo` before `rm`.

Answer (score 1):

Could be something like this?

```
 find -iname '*.o' -not -iname 'example.o' -execdir rm {} \;
```